# Required if validation on array object based on another Field

Tags: php, laravel, validation

How to validate an array object based on another Field. I have an array object details and simple required validation  is working fine with:

```
'details.*.diff_qty' => 'required'
```

But i want to validate it only if item Id is greater than 0 or not equal to zero with .

```
'details.*.diff_qty' => 'required_if:details.*.item_id,!=,0'
```

But not working. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `required_unless`:

```
'details.*.item_id' => 'required',
'details.*.diff_qty' => 'required_unless:details.*.item_id,0'
```

Comment: Item id is not required to be greater than 0 . diff_qty is required only if item id is greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

use something like

`'details.*.diff_qty' =>'required_if:details.*.item_id,gt:details.*.item_id'`